# How to apply Fourier Transform function?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I want to know how I can apply "Fourier Transform function" to an image and then reconstruct the image from the phase information of the Fourier Transform?

Answer (score 0):

Reshape the image, so that each channel has its own 2D matrix.

Normalize the image, so that its values are in the range 0 to 1.

I ~= FFTSHIFT(IFFT(FFT(I))